How to use different Request Transformer instances on service and route at the same time in Kong?
I'm trying to set up a route to a service in kong where both the route and the service use a Request Transformer plugin to make different modifications to the request.
However when I enable the Request Transformer on the route the Request Transformer on the service doesn't seem to have any effect anymore.
The setup I'm trying with has this service:
{
  "port": 8048,
  "path": "/sales",
  "enabled": true,
  "write_timeout": 60000,
  "connect_timeout": 60000,
  "name": "proxied-sales-api",
  "host": "host.docker.internal",
  "protocol": "http",
  "id": "fd910d97-2a72-4414-b977-e90c5187bcbb",
  "retries": 5,
  "read_timeout": 60000
}

With this Request Transformer:
{
  "service": {
    "id": "fd910d97-2a72-4414-b977-e90c5187bcbb"
  },
  "enabled": true,
  "id": "4573853b-c46e-4a85-98d2-0b082bcc694f",
  "config": {
    "add": {
      "headers": [
        "Authorization: Basic ******"
      ]
    }
  },
  "name": "request-transformer",
  "protocols": [
    "grpc",
    "grpcs",
    "http",
    "https"
  ]
}

The route is:
{
  "request_buffering": true,
  "strip_path": true,
  "service": {
    "id": "fd910d97-2a72-4414-b977-e90c5187bcbb"
  },
  "regex_priority": 0,
  "name": "b2b-auth",
  "preserve_host": false,
  "protocols": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "id": "f60c7639-abe3-469a-94b2-4d2d8d5fc492",
  "paths": [
    "/sales-api"
  ],
  "path_handling": "v0",
  "https_redirect_status_code": 426,
  "response_buffering": true
}

With the routes Request Transformer:
{
  "enabled": true,
  "route": {
    "id": "f60c7639-abe3-469a-94b2-4d2d8d5fc492"
  },
  "id": "12aad2ef-d8d0-4ee4-89bf-a36b320cf08e",
  "config": {
    "add": {
      "body": [
        "clientId:buffet-b2b-client",
        "client_secret:foo"
      ],
      "headers": [
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ],
    }
  },
  "name": "request-transformer",
  "protocols": [
    "grpc",
    "grpcs",
    "http",
    "https"
  ]
}

When I test this setup with
curl -v -X POST 'http://localhost:8000/sales-api/buffet/token'

I see the following request being sent to the upstream service:
POST /sales/buffet/token HTTP/1.0
X-Original-URI: /sales/buffet/token
Host: 192.168.127.254:8047
Connection: close
Content-Length: 77
Via: 1.1 kong/3.8.0
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.127.1
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Host: localhost
X-Forwarded-Port: 8000
X-Forwarded-Path: /sales-api/buffet/token
X-Forwarded-Prefix: /sales-api
X-Real-IP: 192.168.127.1
X-Kong-Request-Id: 7df674498166d41480bcde514cc62178
User-Agent: curl/8.8.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

clientId=buffet-b2b-client&client_secret=foo

Why is the request transformer of the service not adding the basic authentication to the request?
I'm using kong 3.8.0 in docker with a windows host.

As stated in the documentation, a single plugin instance always runs once per request.
There exists a precedence on how Kong will choose which plugin, but you cannot make the same plugin run twice on Route and Service.
For your configuration, I think either moving add.header to transformation plugin on Route, or use Post-Plugin to add header on service using kong pdk during access phase.
For post-function, the code will be something like the following:
return function()
    local credentials = 'Basic ******'
    kong.service.request.set_header("Authorization",credentials)
end


If I understand the docs and you correct this means adding a plugin in the kong UI doesn't actually create a new plugin instance but a plugin configuration instead. The plugin instances as in the kong docs are the plugins that have actually been installed in the kong instance. That explains why the Request Transformer is applied to the route and not the service because the route has higher precedence. That is a very questionable design choice in my opinion, because you have to be aware on route and service level what each other entity has been configured with in order to not break anything.

@SpaceTrucker adding a plugin in the kong UI doesn't actually create a new plugin instance not really. Creating a plugin via Kong GUI does create a plugin instance.
The thing is that when a request is routed through Kong, It goes through Route -> Service in this sequence. Kong then choose which plugin instance to use if there are more than one instance of same plugin on the execution.
very questionable design choice, I think it's a very opinionated design choice by Kong. The best we can do is find how to compensate for this design.

I have created https://github.com/Kong/docs.konghq.com/issues/7988 to improve the kong documentation.
